# Selenium handle auto refreshing page

Tags: c#, ajax, selenium

I'm Automating a page use which i don't own the code.
This page refreshes automatically when a new feed is available.

Is there a way to "catch" that refresh with Selenium?

I already tried using

```
firingDriver.ScriptExecuted += new EventHandler<WebDriverScriptEventArgs>(firingDriver_ScriptExecuted);
```

with hope that i'd catch some javascript executing on the page but nothing happened. I think that this event fires *after* Selenium has executed a JavaScript on that page and not the page alone.

Another way (which i don't know if it's possilbe) is to enable FireFox Push Notifications and handle those with Selenium(?)

My code is in C# in case you want to propose a solution.

Comment: Selenium does not provide the concept of listeners and notifiers to a client process to my knowledge. So the best you can do is to poll periodically to see whether (1) the element doesn't exist any longer or if it does, (2) have the contents/attributes of the element have changed. If either is true, a refresh of some kind has occurred.

Comment: @RonNorris , thank you for commenting/answering on this. I've already started implementing the solution you are talking about , i was just hoping something like that existed :D